# Installing wp7 app on microsoft surface tablet

Tags: windows-phone-7, installation

Is there a way to install a wp7 app in a surface tablet? I've trie running the xap file of my app but the os doesn't know what to do with it.

How can I deploy my wp7 app into a surface tablet?

I have the "Pro" edition.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Surface Pro, then you can probably try to install the WP8 SDK and then can probably try to run an emulator, and with a following wind you might eventually be able to deploy your XAP to that emulator.

But there's no way currently to run WP apps on Win8 directly.

Maybe this might come in the next release - currently rumoured to be called "Blue"

Answer (score 1):

The Surface Pro runs Windows and therefore can install Windows apps.  It does run Windows Phone and can't run WP7 apps.

Comment: Just to clarify, I can't install any windows phone 7 app in a surface device?

Comment: No, Windows Phone 7 will only run on a Windows Phone 7 compatible device (of which none are made anymore now that WP8 is out).  You *COULD* run a WP7 app in the development simulator if you had the source code, but that's the extent of it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not directly possible - as another poster said you could try the testing emulator. You might have more luck if it was a windows phone 8 app, because windows 8 on your surface pro is very similar to windows phone 8. A windows phone 8 app can be ported to a tablet windows store app extremely easily, but if you can't do this the emulator is your best bet.